# Include a value and its uncertainty both rounded properly

Tags: siunitx, input

The output of a program is a value and its uncertainty. I want to include them in a tex document correctly rounded.

`value_uncertainty.txt`:

```
12345.67890    0.987654321
```

`scientific_document.tex` is something like:

```
My average number of rabbits is
\SI[figures-of-uncertainty=2]{\input{value_uncertainty.txt}}{\someunits}
```

and the result in scientific_document.pdf is:

```
My average number of rabbits is 12345.68 +- 0.99 SomeUnits
```

Note the rounding of both value and uncertainty even though only the rounding of the uncertainty is specified.
Is it possible?

Comment: @JosephWright It is every day life in science. In sounds really strange to me that does not exist enything like this. Outside siunitx neither?

Answer (score 1):

As a 'native' feature of `siunitx` the current answer is 'no', partly because rounding such that the answer is meaningful when there is an uncertainty is not so straight-forward. Automatic rounding of uncertainties is not necessarily valid: the original aim of `siunitx` was to allow good presentation of material that the user had actually though about, with things like auto-rounding added later. I am aware that people would like such a feature: it's on my 'to do' list, but there are some other issues which I really need to tackle first.

I also note that as you are reading from an external file this suggests either a graphical or tabular display will be most appropriate (probably lots of values). These display formats need to treat the value and uncertainty as separate entities, which can then both be rounded by `siunitx` or by say `pgfplotstable`.