# Automated truncating and compilation of mean and uncertainty pairs for display in table from csv file

Tags: siunitx, csvsimple

I have to display data from a number of CSV files containing pairs of mean and uncertainty values grouped in columns, the first column containing the mean values, the second the uncertainty values and so on.

All entries in the CSV file have six decimal places, but for the display in the table, the data needs to be truncated to pairs with 1, 2 or 3 decimal places. The format I am trying to achieve is displayed in Table 1.

I am  able to create the string I need in principle, using readarray package, but I am missing an automated way to put the strings into the table. I also tried to truncate and load the columns into spearate columns of a tabu table but then I am missing the plusminus sign and the spacing is not ideal (Table 2).

[image]

I guess what I am missing is some kind of lookup loop to store the new pairs in a new matrix and then read the data to the table from the new matrix ?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[textwidth=11cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
N,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,3.035399,0.103098,1.649978,0.049118,1.649978,0.049118
2,0.497626,0.064312,1.391432,0.049175,1.391432,0.049175
3,0.757157,0.112648,0.720012,0.046933,0.720012,0.046933
4,0.529376,0.123559,0.940044,0.048333,0.940044,0.048333
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Truncated string I am trying to put together from the data csv : 

\readdef{data.csv}\data
\readarray\data\names[-,\ncols]
\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\names[2,2]}$\:\pm\:$\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\names[2,3]}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Format I am trying to achieve, using the data from the csv file}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabular}{
        S
        S[table-format = 1.1(1)]
        S[table-format = 1.2(2)]
        S[table-format = 1.3(2)]
        }
        \toprule
        {N} & {one} & {two} & {three} \\
        \midrule
        {1} & 3.0\pm0.1 & 1.65\pm0.02 & 1.650\pm0.049 \\
        {2} & 0.5\pm0.1 & 1.39\pm0.05 & 1.391\pm0.049 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newcolumntype{Z}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=1]}
\newcolumntype{Q}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]}
\newcolumntype{Y}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Loading from csv works, truncating decimal places works, but $\pm$ is missing, spacing is getting to big}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabu} to .8\textwidth {XZZQQYY}
        \toprule
        {N} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{one} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{two} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{three} \\
        \midrule
        \csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\]
        {data.csv}{}{ \N & \A & \B & \C & \D & \E & \F}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. 
If i have overlooked a question answering this, please point it out to me.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! in your mwe are some errors. please test it again and try to eliminate them (... `Invalid token '\names ' in numerical input.` ...)

Comment: I am sorry, but I have tested the MWE again (Texmaker 5.0.2 and Overleaf) and I do not get this error but only a warning concerning the writing of the "data.csv" file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can get some things to work, not rounding with uncertainty though. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127964/105447, which is old, but probably up to date, considering `siunitx`'s documentation states "No rounding will take place if the number contains an uncertainty component."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt gets complicated, because `siunitx` does not round numbers with uncertainty components (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127964/105447, which is old, but seems to be still valid).

You can cheat `siunitx` by building each column individually, as shown below. But I must say I'm not very fond of going around `siunitx` because, usually, it disciplines your document to get things in a proper way.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[textwidth=11cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
N,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,3.035399,0.103098,1.649978,0.049118,1.649978,0.049118
2,0.497626,0.064312,1.391432,0.049175,1.391432,0.049175
3,0.757157,0.112648,0.720012,0.046933,0.720012,0.046933
4,0.529376,0.123559,0.940044,0.048333,0.940044,0.048333
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Truncated string I am trying to put together from the data csv :

\readdef{data.csv}\data
\readarray\data\names[-,\ncols]
\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\names[2,2]}$\:\pm\:$\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\names[2,3]}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Format I am trying to achieve, using the data from the csv file}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabular}{
        S
        S[table-format = 1.1(1)]
        S[table-format = 1.2(2)]
        S[table-format = 1.3(2)]
        }
        \toprule
        {N} & {one} & {two} & {three} \\
        \midrule
        {1} & 3.0\pm0.1 & 1.65\pm0.02 & 1.650\pm0.049 \\
        {2} & 0.5\pm0.1 & 1.39\pm0.05 & 1.391\pm0.049 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newcolumntype{Z}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2,table-format = 1.6(7)]}
\newcolumntype{Q}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2,table-format = 1.6(7)]}
\newcolumntype{Y}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=3,table-format = 1.6(7)]}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Loading from csv works, $\pm$ works, but rounding doesn’t}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabu} to .8\textwidth {XZQY}
        \toprule
        {N} & {one} & {two} & {three} \\
        \midrule
        \csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\]
        {data.csv}{}{\N & \A\pm\B & \C\pm\D & \E\pm\F}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}


\newcolumntype{T}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=1,table-format = 1.1]}
\newcolumntype{R}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2,table-format = 1.2]}
\newcolumntype{P}{S[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=3,table-format = 1.3]}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Loading from csv works, truncating decimal places works, $\pm$ works}
    \medskip
    \begin{tabular}{XT@{\pm}TR@{\pm}RP@{\pm}P}
        \toprule
        {N} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{one} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{two} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{three} \\
        \midrule
        \csvreader[head to column names, late after line=\\]
        {data.csv}{}{\N & \A & \B & \C & \D & \E & \F}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi gusbrs, thanks for your answer. I am quiet happy with that solution, since it allows to specify the decimals places for the uncertainty columns for each pair individually, which in my understanding is close to the second part of Joseph Wrights answer ("These display formats need to treat the value and uncertainty as separate entities, which can then both be rounded"), at least on a column level.

Comment: @kurechan I'm glad to hear. Btw, that's a nice first question. Keep it up!  ;-)